# Using useEffect to get data from an api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data from an API every time a user creates a new post. And I know that if you want to make the request happen when the data changes you can use this:

```
 const [tweets, setTweets] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
       api.get('tweets').then(response => setTweets(response.data))
       
    }, [tweets])
```

It works, and I don't need to refresh the page to see the new post that has been created. But when I go to Inspect in my app and then to Network, I can see that infinite amounts of GET requests happen, even if I specified the call only when the array changes. Can someone tell me how to solve it? (I don't know if it's normal to happen or something that I need to be worried about)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `tweets` from the array of dependencies:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
       api.get('tweets').then(response => setTweets(response.data))

    }, [])
```

That array means, "whenever one of these values changes, re-run the function". So the function is getting run, getting new tweets, and then getting re-run because `tweets` changes; that's the infinite loop.

Comment: if I remove the tweets, I'll have to refresh the page to see the new post

Answer (score 1):

**Issue** is `useEffect` dependency `[tweets]`:

so as per your code it will call `useEffect` whenever there is a change in `tweets`,

inside `useEffect` you are updating it, so

```
useEffect --> setTweets --> useEffect --> setTweets --> ....
```

---

**Solution :**

```
useEffect(() => {
       api.get('tweets').then(response => setTweets(response.data))
//}, [tweets]) // <--- remove tests from here
}, [])
```

---

As per the comment, you can do something like this :

unmounted is just for to not to get in error of "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component."

```
useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false; 
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
       api.get('tweets').then(response => { 
           // you can compare the current tweets with new also and update state only after that
           if(!unmounted)
                setTweets(response.data)
       })
    },5000)
    return () => { 
        unmounted = true;
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: but if I make this, the request will happen only when the component mounts, and I won't be able to see the new post unless I refresh the page, and I don't want this to happen

Comment: @GabrielTisoVinhasdeBrito,so when do you want new posts?

Comment: when the user submits a new one

Comment: do you have a suggestion/

Comment: I don't know if it's normal, but I keep getting GET requests when I check Network (in a much slower rate, that's good). Is it normal, or I have to implement another functionality in your code?

Comment: You can increase the timer to make it more slower , or just call the if you know when you get new tweet.

Comment: below the if statement I added another if like this:                                
        if(response.data.length === tweets.length) 
                  alert('no need to update'), and as expected, after 5 seconds I get this alert. I want the api to get data only when this condotion is not true, how can I do that?

Comment: This is not how you should check you need to compare each tweets by looping, and I think your main issue is solved you should accept and upvote the answer.